# Caching different types of model instances

Tags: python, django, memcached

It's possible to cache list with different types of objects in django? When i'm trying to do this, django always return None to me.

Check this code:

```
foo = Foo.objects.all()[:10]
bar = Bar.objects.all()[:10]
foobar = list(foo) + list(bar)
cache.set('foobar', foobar)
cache.get('foobar') # None
```

If this is normal behaviour, is there some workarounds?

Comment: Did you make django cache settings correctly, as far as i remember, cache fails silently, so you get no error messages if there appears an error while setting/getting cache value. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/cache/#django-s-cache-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django could cache such list, you need to check

- `cache.set('foo', 'bar')` then `get` to ensure the cache works
- the log of the cache backend to know whether `set` succeeds
- for memcached backend, whether `foobar` is too big to fit in the cache

Comment: yep, turns out, `foobar` was more than 1mb memcached value limit. thanks